# How can I use the vector datatype in a header-file in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, header-files

I have this struct below for matrixes. It has worked properly when I had declared it in my main.cpp, but since the program became more complex, I decided to swap it out. So my header file looks like this:

```
    #ifndef MATRIX_STRUCT_H
    #define MATRIX_STRUCT_H

    #include <vector>

    // Matrix datatype
    struct matrix_ {
        // Matrix dimension m x n
        unsigned int dimX; // n
        unsigned int dimY; // m
        bool square;
        // Matrix coefficients
        vector <vector <double>> coef;
    };
    typedef struct matrix_ matrix;

    #endif // MATRIX_STRUCT_H
```

The problem I have now is, that line 4 `#include <vector>` makes no difference if it is here or not. I always get the error for line 13

```
error: 'vector' does not name a type
```

If you're wondering why I'm using a struct and not a class, I simply arrived only recently from C, so I don't have any experiences with classes yet.

Does anybody can help me, please? Would it be better (would it help) to abandon the structs and concentrate on classes only?

Comment: `std::vector`, not just `vector`.

Comment: That's cause it's spelled `std::vector`.

Comment: `vector` is defined in `namespace std{}`. You should use it's full name qualifier: `std::vector<>`

Comment: This is not your primary issue, but C++ is not C, and in particular you don't need to use `typedef` to make `matrix` available without the `struct` keyword. You can just call it `struct matrix` and use `matrix`. Also, it might be preferable to make `square` a member function: `bool square() const { return dimX == dimY; }`.

Comment: You are missing the namespace `std`. The declaration of your coefficients should read as `sd::vector<std::vector<double>> coef;`

Comment: The keyword `struct` defines a class type. The only difference with the keyword `class` is that members and bases of `struct` declared classes are `public` by default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ standard library includes put new declarations in the `std` namespace. You need to write `std::vector` instead of just `vector`.

Likely the reason that it worked in your .cpp file is that you have the line `using namespace std` somewhere near the top which brings everything from the namespace `std` and brings it into the local namespace. This [is bad practice](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/) and I recommend you stop doing it.

Comment: Worth saying (in case the OP is tempted) that although it's bad practise in a cpp file, but it's simply wrong in a header file as it may make correct code that includes the header file uncompilable.